# Picking out the last item of a NodeList - java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I've manage to parse an XML file with some distances in kilometers. But as result I get list of distances of cource, but the last element in the list contains the sum of all the other elements in the list. How can I grab **the last** element in the list

Some source code:

```
for(int s=0; s<listOfRoutes.getLength() ; s++){
    NodeList listDist = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    totalDist = listDist.getLength(); 

    for (int k = 0; k<listDist.getLength(); k++) {
        NodeList childs = listDist.item(k).getChildNodes();

        for (int l = 0; l < childs.getLength(); l++) {
            if (childs.item(l).getNodeName().equals("text")) {
            System.out.println(childs.item(l).getTextContent());
                //totalKM.add(childs.item(l).getTextContent()); 
            }       
        }

     }  
     System.out.println("Total Distances: " + totalDist); 
 }
```

I'am interested in the last element of the childs NodeList, which contains this information:

```
0.3 km
0.8 km
0.9 km
0.3 km
0.1 km
0.3 km
40 m
0.3 km
3.0 km
```

How can I grab this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `listDist.item(listDist.getLength() - 1)` work?